# crash on ubuntu but normally on Mac when get instance out from sqlie blob

Tags: sqlite, ubuntu

I had saved a class instance in blob field using sqlite-db.
The table policyRule have only one field which is "blob" type.
Now I get it out from the table, which is run normally in macOS but ubuntu.
Would you give me some advice?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class SENDFILERULE
{
public:
    string a; 
    int b;
    string c;

};

void doTest()
{
    sqlite3* conn = NULL;
    int result = sqlite3_open("mytest.db",&conn);
    if (result != SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        sqlite3_close(conn);
        return;
    }
    char createTableSQL[1024];
    sprintf(createTableSQL,"%s","CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS policyRule (rule blob)");

    sqlite3_stmt* stmt = NULL;
    //8.read from database
    const char* selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM  policyRule";
    stmt = NULL;
   if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(conn,selectSQL,strlen(selectSQL),&stmt,NULL) !=SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        if (stmt)
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        sqlite3_close(conn);
        return;
    }
    do
    {
        int ret = sqlite3_step(stmt);
        if (ret == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {
            char* buf =(char*)malloc(1024);
            memset(buf,0,1024);
            buf = (char*)sqlite3_column_blob(stmt,0); 

            SENDFILERULE* pRule =reinterpret_cast<SENDFILERULE*>(buf);
            printf("%s %d   %s \n",pRule->a.c_str(),pRule->b,pRule->c.c_str());

        }
        else if(ret == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            printf("select end \n");
            break;
        }
    }while(1);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}

int main()
{
    doTest();
    return 0;
}
```

when I print the pRule->b, it is ok, but the string type.

Comment: You cannot store `string` in a blob.

Comment: yeah, how can I save the object in db, serialize it?

Comment: That depends on what you actually want to store, and you how want to use it. Why don't you use three columns?